# Sync AD groups with Sharepoint 2010 Programmatically

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, active-directory, sync, active-directory-import

Can someone help me with an example of this.
How to sync changes in AD groups with SharePoint groups progammatically?

Comment: check this one http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95170/syncronizing-ad-groups-to-sharepoint-user-list-through-powershell

Comment: also, it is for 2007 but give you idea...http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/programmatically-syncing-active-161564.aspx

Comment: Can this be done in C#?

Comment: 2nd link is with c#

Comment: i just add these comment as answer, if you want then close the question by marking anwser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you setup the User profile then no need of it but here are couple of links which will help you.

Use Powershell:

[Syncronizing AD groups to sharepoint user list (through powershell?)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95170/syncronizing-ad-groups-to-sharepoint-user-list-through-powershell)

Using the C#

http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/programmatically-syncing-active-161564.aspx

Comment: Hi @waqas sarwar MCSE

Comment: Hi @waqas sarwar MCSE I have a basic question as I am new to sharepoint. 
Where do you write this C# code to add AD users to Sharepoint users? is it in VS 2012? If so in a project/solution and deploy it? Can you please explain it in detail? Thanks in advance

Comment: i would recommend, create another question. you will get better answer and details....